# Build dynamic library for project fails! - android cocos

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Im new to cocos2d and trying to build the android project for first time in mac OS maverics.
I have downloaded the new version of cocos2dx3.2 android SDK NDK v9 and the ANT.
When im going to build the project is shows a error like

```
Build dynamic library for project [ /Users/Lahiru/Desktop/Cocos/cocos2dx/build/../tests/cpp-tests/proj.android ] fails!
```

my .bashprofile is like this

```
# Add environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT=/Users/Lahiru/Desktop/Cocos/cocos2dx/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
export PATH=$COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable NDK_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export NDK_ROOT=/Users/Lahiru/Desktop/Cocos/androidndkr9
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/Lahiru/Desktop/Cocos/adtbundle/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH

# Add environment variable ANT_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export ANT_ROOT=/Users/Lahiru/Desktop/Cocos/apacheant194/bin
export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Can anyone guide me what did I missed?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try switch from ndk9b to ndk9d.
the recent version of cocos2dx made a switch from ndk9b to ndk9d.